# Create a custom map using an image with pins that can be filtered. Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, imagemap

I am wanting to add a map to an app I have created that has pin overlays that can be filtered using checkboxes and a search option that can be used to search for a specific location on the map.

I will not be using google maps for this.

For example, a custom image of a map (say for a campus or a shopping mall etc) that is laid out into a grid (A-Z for lat + 1-26 for lon).  I want to have a few different pins laid out around the map and be able to filter them on or off using check boxes.  I also want to have a few locations that can be searched for on the map.  There is not necessarily going to be any need for the user to be able to add a custom pin onto the map on their device at this point.

I honestly have no idea where to start here as I have not been able to find any real documentation that seems relevant to what I am trying to achieve here.  I am fairly new to apps, and my current app that I want to add this into has been made with Xamarin Android for Visual Studio 2017.

I have been reading about imageMap but it seems that it needs to load information from an external source, but I am unsure.  I need the app/map to run properly offline so I want to have the image packaged in with the resources so it can be installed to the device with the app.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or idea's that any of you more experienced and skilled app dev guru's may have for me.

Comment: Hi, your question is really widely, so what is your problem? Don't know how to start it?

Comment: Pretty much, I dont know where to begin with this.  I want to turn an image into a map style thing that in pinch zoomable and can have pre programmed pins that can be turned on and off with checkbox filters.  Im really new to android apps, this is literally the first app I have made and I want to add this feature.  The whole thing is really just a learning experience.